# StructureMap ASP.net MVC Not Injecting Interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, structuremap

I have tried to get the structure map dependency to work correctly but it is not working correctly when putting an interface in the constructor versus putting the class name.

The following code works:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly MyService _service;

    public HomeController(MyService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}

public class MyService : IService
{
    public string GetName()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
}

public interface IService
{
    string GetName();
}
```

But the following code does NOT work:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IService _service;

    public HomeController(IService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}

public class MyService : IService
{
    public string GetName()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
}

public interface IService
{
    string GetName();
}
```

Here is the logic from the DependencyResolution class:

```
  public static IContainer Initialize() {
        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
                    {
                        x.Scan(scan =>
                                {
                                    scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                                    scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                                });
        //                x.For<IExample>().Use<Example>();
                    });
        return ObjectFactory.Container;
    }
```

I am using the StructureMap.MVC4 nuget package to setup the dependency injection. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Post the code where you set up the StructureMap bindings?

Comment: I guess I should of used x.For<IService>().Use<MyService>();

Comment: Is there a way to have it assume the MyService if there is only one in referenced assemblies?

Comment: @Jonathan - the `WithDefaultConventions()` should actually do that for you, so I'm not sure why it's not.  Maybe they have to also be in the same namespace?

Comment: @mmillican I could be wrong but I believe WithDefaultConventions maps `IFoo` to `Foo`. In this case he wants to map `IFoo` to `MyFoo` Given that this seems to be a toy example, changing the type name is probably a good solution.

Comment: @BenAaronson Ah you're right... I missed that.

Comment: Yeah my real world example is more like IService<Product> should be injected.

Comment: @mmillican is correct. The default conventions require the interface to be named the same as the implementation and have the "I" prefix. In this case the interface should have been called IMyService or registered in the container explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your calling assembly if you have only single implementation class representing a inteface you can use like below

```
x.Scan(scan =>
             {
               scan.TheCallingAssembly();
               scan.WithDefaultConventions();
               scan.SingleImplementationsOfInterface();
             });
```

without SingleImplementationsOfInterface() method structuremap can not identify the proper implementation class for the IService interface .

or

you can map like below

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.Scan(scan =>
            {
                scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                scan.WithDefaultConventions();
            });
            x.For<IService>().Use<MyService>();
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

try this piece of code instead:

```
 public class MvcBootStrapper
        {
            public static void ConfigurationStructureMap()
            {
                ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
                {
                    x.AddRegistry<MyService>();
                });
            }
        }
```

and finally register you classes and interfaces like this:

```
 public class SampleRegistery : Registry
        {
            public SampleRegistery ()
            {
                ForRequestedType<IService>().TheDefaultIsConcreteType<MyService>();
            }
        }
```

see [this](http://ehsanghanbari.com/Post/4/inversion-of-control-container-concept-and-related-tools) article for more info.